# Is there any quick way to generate multi bitrate DASH & HLS streams from a video file?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, adaptive-bitrate

I've used bitmovin.com  that generates dash & hls streams I want. 
But, I don't want a cloud service.

I need to generate those streams locally on my machine.
A utility or shell script that takes the 1080p video as input, then outputs multi bitrate dash & hls files

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. [Bento4](https://www.bento4.com/) works fine with MP4s but you have to encode the variants with something like [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) beforehand.

Comment: Thanks aergistal.

Comment: @aergistal

I'm looking for somthing like https://github.com/bentasker/HLS-Stream-Creator, https://www.npmjs.com/package/rmp-segment

However, They're not offering the solution for creating HLS & DASH I want. I'm in a need of a shell script that uses Bento4/FFMpeg/MP4box or whatever takes one input then gives multiple outputs in different resolution & bitrate _Just one command_ .

Moreover, reinventing a wheel is not good. I hope there can be a solution come though SOF